# Mysql join query with group by

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in my db

posts table (id,title,data) and tags table (id,post_id,tags)

Example data in tags table

Example data in tags table:

```
id  post_id tag
1   1   PHP
2   1   JS
3   2   C
4   2   C++
5   2   MySql
```

Posts table

```
id title date
1  post1 12/05/2015
2  post2  12/05/2016
```

I want an output like this

Example output:

```
id  title   tags
1   Post1   PHP, JS
2   Post2   C, C++,MySql
```

How can i write one single query obtain the result like this

Currently i performs a left join

```
SELECT * FROM  posts  LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.post_id=posts.id GROUP BY tags.post_id
```

I know group concat is used to obtain this result but i don't know how to use it

Comment: what you want to do with group by ?

Comment: I got confused with group by

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks for the progress report.

Comment: @BlessanKurien I think my answer will help you to join with comma seperated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use group GROUP_CONCAT to get result as a comma separated value:

```
SELECT posts.id
     , posts.title
     , GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag) 
  FROM  posts  
  LEFT 
  JOIN tags 
    ON tags.post_id = posts.id  
 GROUP 
    BY posts.id
```